# How to read protect Amazon S3 folder/object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

**I have a situation in which I want to read protect an Amazon S3 folder**

I am calling a batch job from my API to read  an Amazon S3 folder. The API will run on multiple instances.

When a batch job is reading the folder contents and processing it, in the mean time if any other batch job wants to read the same folder, the 2nd batch job should not be allowed to read the folder. (as it is read protected). After the processing is done there should option using which the folder can be readable again and read lock should not be there.

**How can achieve to read protect the Amazon S3 folder/object?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please define "read protect".

Comment: The object should not be allowed to read by the API while it is protected or locked. Initially I though I can use S3 Object Lock feature, but it is protects from deleting the object.

Comment: I am thinking of creating a flag (say a file as metadata) to store in the s3 folder which I want to protect while one instance of API is working on it.  During this time if any other API wants to access the S3 folder, it will check if the metadata (the flag) exists or not. If exists, don't process the folder data. And that's how you can protect the folder from other api request who wants to work on the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of "read protecting" Amazon S3 objects.

You might want to take a different approach so that the batch jobs do not overlap. For example, **messages could be sent to an Amazon SQS queue** with the name of a folder to process. Each 'worker' then takes a message off the SQS queue and processes that folder. This way, the workers are being assigned specific work rather than trying to "protect" them from each other.

As an example, think of **multiple people trying to clean a house**. Each person could be 'assigned' a room to clean from a central list. This is better than having each person attempt to go into every room to see whether it needs cleaning, and then needing to lock the door of a room while it is being cleaned.

Comment: Thanks @John for your suggestion. I can implement the SQS concept. The batches are triggered by API call with folder name. So, multiple batch can be called with the same  folder name as a source to process. I don't have control over this logic to not allow multiple batch with same folder name. So, even if I implement SQS, two workers(batch jobs)  can start working on same folder, right?

Comment: You could use a FIFO SQS queue, with the folder as the `MessageGroupID`. A FIFO queue will not provide additional messages from the same `MessageGroupID` while a message is being processed ("in flight"). See: [Using the Amazon SQS message group ID - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html)